# How to Open a link in a new browser window in sfdc lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Below is the thing I tried but it opens in a new tab instead of new browser window. Can anyone please suggest how it can be open in a new browser window?

```
 <span onclick="{!c.openActionWindow}"><a>View Service Request in Siebel</a></span>

Controller:

  openActionWindow : function(component,event,helper){
         window.open('https://www.w3schools.com','_blank');  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this though you have to set screen size

```
<a onclick="{!c.clicked}">View Service Request in Siebel</a>
```

js

```
clicked : function(component, event, helper) {
         window.open('https://www.w3schools.com','newwindow', 'width=3000,height=2500');
}
```

Comment: awesome!! Thanks for the help! just a single line answer and I searched the whole net to find out nothing! great @User6670!!!